# Separate copy of DbContext class for unit testing?

Tags: entity-framework-core, xunit, bogus

I have a `CatalogDbContext` class.

I want to use [`Bogus`](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/tree/master/Examples/EFCoreSeedDb) library to seed fake data into the database that my unit tests will use.

The [example](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/tree/master/Examples/EFCoreSeedDb) provided in bogus's github repo makes use of the `HasData` method of the `CatalogDbContext` class to seed data into the tables.

However, I will not want this `HasData` method to be executed from the API - meaning, the `HasData` method should only be run if the DBContext is created from the Unit Tests.

Kindly advise how to achieve this?.

```cs
using Bogus;
using Catalog.Api.Database.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Catalog.Api.Database
{
    public class CatalogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CatalogDbContext(DbContextOptions<CatalogDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<CatalogItem> CatalogItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CatalogBrand> CatalogBrands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CatalogType> CatalogTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CatalogBrandEntityTypeConfiguration());
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CatalogTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CatalogItemEntityTypeConfiguration());

            FakeData.Init(10);

            builder.Entity<CatalogItem>().HasData(FakeData.CatalogItems);
        }
    }

    internal class FakeData
    {
        public static List<CatalogItem> CatalogItems = new List<CatalogItem>();

        public static void Init(int count)
        {
            var id = 1;

            var catalogItemFaker = new Faker<CatalogItem>()
                .RuleFor(ci => ci.Id, _ => id++)
                .RuleFor(ci => ci.Name, f => f.Commerce.ProductName());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) This would be an [integration test](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+an+integration+test+site%3Astackoverflow.com), not a `unit test`. 2) You should put an interface in front of `CatalogDbContext` and then use `Moq` or similar in your unit tests for `ICatalogDbContext`. 3) If you want an integration test, then the integration test should use a different db connection and then seed the integration db w/ the data from `bogus`.

Comment: If you need to reference the same classes from multiple projects, then make a class library project, and have both projects reference that class library.

Comment: SO community, I am still awaiting an answer!

Comment: You're not *entitled* to getting answers. You had two people interested, you should have savored that by responding. They might have been willing to work with you unto an answer.